# import error when run tests in submodule with nose

Tags: python, git-submodules, nose

We use git submodule to share common module within our team.

Each module has test cases in its source folder, and ran by nose.

I have a project in this structure:

```
/project_sample
|__/project_sample
|  |__ __init__.py
|  |__ moduleA.py
|  |__/tests
|  |  |__ __init__.py
|  |  |__ moduleA_tests.py
|  |__/subpackage
|     |__ __init__.py
|     |__ moduleB.py
|     |__/tests
|        |__ __init__.py
|        |__ moduleB_tests.py
|__setup.py
```

All of these **init**.py files are empty.

The subpackage is developed seperately and added to the project by git submodule. We want it to be self-contained , and try to share it in different project. Its test case is like this:

```
moduleB_tests.py:

from subpackage import moduleB

def test_funcA():
    moduleB.funcA()
```

The test pass when i run `nosetests` from the subpackage's repo folder.

Seems like nose find a **init**.py file in the parent folder of subpackage (project_sample), when i run `nosetests` from project_sample's root directory, i get `"ImportError: No module named subpackage"`. But it passed when i change the first line to:

```
from project_sample.subpackage import moduleB
```

But this way makes subpackage not self-contained.

I tried some way like : adding subpackage to `sys.path` or use `-w` option of nose, but still get this exception.

My teammate run subpackage's test case seperately in PyCharm and get passed, so i think there should be some way to make it pass from command line.

Is there any way to resolve the problem, or any suggestion with the project structure?

This is my first question on SO, Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want subpackage to be self-contained, you need it to treat as such. This means that you need to put it top-level, parallel to `project_sample` instead of into it.

Comment: It can fix this problem, but it means we can't make the package dependeies hierarchically, and its distribution will contains several folders. I find same famous lib (like requests) arrange their packages hierarchically, so there should be other ways.

Comment: Can you point me to the code in requests that does what you try? Mind you: having several folder deep (or better: package deep) hierarchies is not a problem in Python, but it is *also* not the problem you are having. You try to have a package appear under two different names - which is not supported (at least not without creating possible alias-problem with other modules by haphazardly messing with `sys.path`). If you want self-contained, use top-level, don't embed somewhere deep within a module-hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for ur advice. In my mind, if a package is self-contained, it can be placed anywhere. I think my problem is mainly with unit tests, especially with the way nose found and run tests. The project runs well without these tests.

Comment: @soulcoder Minds and reality not necessarily coincide :) self-contained in Python's understanding is different from ur. You can "fight the system", but this comes at a cost. If you add `project_sample` to `sys.path`, you can "fix" your problem. But that will make e.g. `moduleA` a top-level module as well, that can be imported as `import moduleA` instead of `import project_sample.moduleA`. Which might lead to subtle bugs with module variables that start existing twice. So again, my very serious advice is: don't do this. pip doesn't install requests *into* your project. It installs it alongside.

Comment: I find your opinion is right when i make several project contains the same subpackage, and each of them may has some dependencies, then i have several copies of the subpackage in a project. hah !

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old and has already been answered but we use a different strategy in our code base.

If for some reason you still want the package in the project_sample module directory, you can structure it something like this:

```
/project_sample
|__/project_sample
|  |__ __init__.py
|  |__ moduleA.py
|  |__/tests
|  |  |__ __init__.py
|  |  |__ moduleA_tests.py
|  |__/subpackage_repo
|     |__/subpackage
|        |__ __init__.py
|        |__ moduleB.py
|        |__/tests
|           |__ __init__.py
|           |__ moduleB_tests.py
|     |__setup.py
|__setup.py
```

Without an `__init__.py` in the subpackage, it won't be a part of your project.

Then in the `__init__.py` of the main package, you can include

```py
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0,
                os.path.join(
                    os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
                    'subpackage_repo')
)

import subpackage
```

which puts the subpackage in the path for the main project.

Then in `moduleA.py` that allows us to do something like

```py
from . import subpackage
```

since the package is imported at the `__init__.py` level.

Of course you can also move it up a level as well and just reflect that in the path you're adding if you want to do it that way. The only disadvantage of doing that is that when you run your tests with something like

```
python -m unittest discover
```

you'll discover the subpackage tests as well and run those. Ideally those tests should be taken care of with whatever CI you have for the package so we'd hope that they don't need to be run.